# CMake Error Findurdf.cmake

Tags: catkin-make, catkin, ros-indigo, ur5

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm running the UR5-package on indigo against Ubuntu 14.04.
Everything works fine, but since a while I get the following error when catkin_make my workspace.

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/kdl_parser/cmake/kdl_parserConfig.cmake:165 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findurdf.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "urdf", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "urdf" with any of
  the following names:

    urdfConfig.cmake
    urdf-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "urdf" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "urdf_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "urdf"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/indigo/share/moveit_core/cmake/moveit_coreConfig.cmake:165 (find_package)
  /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:75 (find_package)
  universal_robot/ur_kinematics/CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/geissler/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/geissler/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

I did not knowingly change anything.
Anybody knows where that does come from?

Best regards

P.S.: please note I'm a beginner concerning ROS...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204329/cmake-error-findurdf.cmake/) by [bluefish](https://answers.ros.org/users/21682/bluefish/) on ROS Answers with karma: 236 on 2015-03-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-03-05**:
Just to make sure: try deleting your `build/` and `devel/` directories. Then rebuild your workspace.

**Comment by [bluefish](https://answers.ros.org/users/21682/bluefish/) on 2015-03-06**:
I deleted both, rebuilt the workspace but got the same error then :(

**Comment by [bluefish](https://answers.ros.org/users/21682/bluefish/) on 2015-03-06**:
As described in the answer I chose the way of reinstalling ROS and it is working.
Thanks for your support!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Okay, I uninstalled ROS completely (debian packages and their configs) via

```
sudo apt-get purge ros-indigo-*
```

and reinstalled it like described in the tutorial. Then reinstalled the moveit-package and catkin_make the workspace and everything is working well again. (I did not change the workspace).

I guess something was broken in the opt/ros/* folders. Weird...

Thanks gvdhoorn for support!!

---

Originally posted by [bluefish](https://answers.ros.org/users/21682/bluefish/) with karma: 236 on 2015-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've just tried to reproduce this on an up-to-date (2015-03-06) Indigo install with a clone of `universal_robot` in a catkin workspace. Everything compiles normally for me. Are you using the debians of `universal_robot`, or a from-source? Could you try a fresh workspace?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-03-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2